# "Hidden" attributes or duplicated code in python when using inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, module, object-oriented-analysis

I have a question about what I see as a potential bad habit when using inheritance in python

suppose I have a base class

```
class FourLeggedAnimal():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.number_of_legs = 4
```

and two daughter classes

```
class Cat(FourLeggedAnimal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def claw_the_furniture(self):
        for leg in range(self.number_of_legs):
        print("scratch")
```

```
class Dog(FourLeggedAnimal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
     
    def run_in_sleep(self):
        for leg in range(self.number_of_legs):
        self.move_leg(leg)

    def move_leg(i):
        pass
```

For the purposes of this example, I intend to keep `Animal` in a **different file** than `Cat`. For someone reading the code for the `Cat` or `Dog` class, the `number_of_legs` attribute is used but not defined in the file. My understanding is that it is best not to have variables whose definitions are opaque (which is why its best to avoid `from x import *`.

I see the alternative to be repeating the definition `self.number_of_legs` in both daughter classes but that defeats the purposes of inheritance.

Is there a best-practice to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: A comment, I suggest.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if everyone will agree with my opinion, but from work experience I have learned that a lot of my coworkers actually prefer to have variables abstracted away from certain files(meaning they are defined elsewhere). In my opinion, I don't see anything wrong with that style and actually prefer it. Most IDE's will also have a 'go to definition' option where others can see where that variable is defined. Again, just my personal opinion.

Comment: The definition is not really "opaque".  `number_of_legs` is qualified by `self`, so if it is not defined in the subclass then it must be defined in a superclass.  Duplicating the definition is at best unhelpful, and could potentially lead to bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that it is best not to have variables whose definitions are opaque (which is why its best to avoid from x import *.

I think perhaps you are misunderstanding the source of this advice. It may even be a mix of different pieces of advice. I'll try to explain what I think might have been the underlying ideas people were trying to convey.

Firstly, it's pretty widely agreed that `from x import *` is best avoided in Python. This is because it makes it hard for readers to find out where a name comes from or indeed if it's defined at all. It also confuses some code analysis tools. It's the only way that a (non-builtin) name will normally get into a top level namespace without appearing in the source code and being easy to search for. As far as this advice goes, it's *only* for this case. You could barely write Python code at all if you couldn't use fields and methods on objects, and you generally have a clear breadcrumb trail to follow. (Moreso if you're using type annotations.)

However, you may also be thinking of the principle of encapsulation. In object-oriented programming it's considered preferable to separate the *interface* from the *implementation* of your objects. You make the interface as small, simple and clear as you can and hide away the implementation from the code *using* the objects. In this way you can reason about and change the implementation in isolation, with confidence that doing so won't affect other code. This principle is applied even between base classes and sub-classes - the sub-class shouldn't "know" anything about the base class that it doesn't need to. Now, modifying variables, and to a lesser extent reading modifiable variables requires knowing an awful lot about what expectations the base class has for their values, their relationship with other state and when it's possible/permissible for them to change. Depending on them can make it much harder to safely change the base class.

Now, Python does have more flexibility than some other languages in this respect. In Python you can seamlessly replace a variable with a property, and thus make "reading" and "setting" a field into methods that you can implement however you want. In other languages once a sub-class starts using a field exposed by a base class it is impossible to refactor the base class to remove the field or add any extra behaviour when it is accessed, unless you also update all the sub-classes. So it's a *bit* less of a concern. Or rather, there's no particular reason to treat fields differently from methods.

With all this in mind, the question becomes - what interface is your base class presenting to its sub-classes? Does it support them setting as well as reading this field? Can you reduce the size and complexity of the interface between the two classes without making your code more complex? An interface is simpler and easier to reason about if it is read-only, and moreso if it does not involve mutable state at all. Where possible the base class should not give the sub-class any unnecessary opportunities to break its invariants. (I.e. it's expectations about its own state.) In Python these things are more often achieved through convention (e.g. fields and methods beginning with an underscore are considered not to be part of the public interface unless documented otherwise) and documentation than through language features.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a best-practice to deal with this kind of situation?

Normally, class variables are used for this purpose.

```
class FourLeggedAnimal():
    number_of_legs = 4                    # class variable

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Cat(FourLeggedAnimal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)

    def claw_the_furniture(self):
        for leg in range(self.number_of_legs):
            print("scratch")

class Dog(FourLeggedAnimal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
     
    def run_in_sleep(self):
        for leg in range(self.number_of_legs):
            self.move_leg(leg)

    def move_leg(i):
        pass
```

Note that even if these classes are in different files, the attribute is part of the parent's public API and is knowable by the subclasses.  Also, the class name, "FourLeggedAnimal" does a great job of communicating what the number of legs would be.